# how to solve runtime error '6' overflow issue in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make both column A and column B empty when any row of cell value in column B has the word: "NEW". I've had total of  278005 lines in Columns C and I got the overflow error when I run my code. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

```
Sub dltnew()
    Dim i As Double
    Dim lrow As Double
    lrow = Sheets("today").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lrow
      If Sheets("today").Cells(i, 2).Value = "NEW" Then
        Sheets("today").Cells(i, 2).Value = ""
        Sheets("today").Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
      End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Start off with `Dim i As Long, lrow As Long` . It's likely not the root of your problem but call a row number what it actually is, a long integer not a floating point decimal number.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the **exact error number and text** please.

Comment: It isn't clear why column C is even relevant if it is columns A and B that you need to modify. There also isn't any obvious reason that you would get overflow with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Any form of bulk operation is going to be more efficient than your cuurent method of looping through the cells. An [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx) seems a likely candidate to speed things up.

```
Sub dltnew()

    On Error Goto bm_Safe_Exit
    appTGGL bTGGL:=False

    With Worksheets("today")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="new"
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 2).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    .Cells.ClearContents
                End If
            End With
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

bm_Safe_Exit:        
    appTGGL

End Sub

Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
        .EnableEvents = bTGGL
        .DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
        .Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    End With
End Sub
```

Additional efficiency could be gained by turning off screen updating, calculation, event handling, etc. I've moved their code to a small helper sub rather than repeat it twice in the main sub.

Comment: Hi Jeeped. Thank you for your reply. I've just tried to change the dim of all related code from 'integer' to 'long'. The excel file is still running and trying to open the workbook itself. I'll try your code and let you know how it goes after this.

Comment: Hi jeeped. After I changed from 'Integer' to 'Long', the excel file runs extremely slow. Also, I've had 'code excecution has been interrupted' error when I tried to stop the file from running the code endlessly.